# Add WMS to matplotlib Python

Tags: python, wms, geopandas, basemap, matplotlib

Currently I am adding a basemap from stamen.com to my plots as it is explained here: http://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html .

Is it also possible to load a WMS from another source as basemap?

I'm interested in this one: http://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_topplus_open

Comment: See https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/wms.html for a way not using geopandas

Comment: have you tried it with the link posted by nmtoken? looks good to me but i han´t had time trying it yet